# What happens with the absolute value from $\left|\frac 1{an+b}\right|<\varepsilon$ to $n>\frac{|b|+1/\varepsilon}{|a|}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression $\left|\frac 1{an+b}\right|<\varepsilon$, so $n>\frac{|b|+1/\varepsilon}{|a|}$. What I don't understand is how to manipulate the absolute value in order to get that.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that $\frac{1}{a}n+b$, $\frac{1}{an}+b$ or $\frac{1}{an+b}$?

Comment: The last one. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm assuming you define $n$ to be positive. $|\frac{1}{an+b}|<\epsilon$ does not just by itself imply $n>\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon}+|b|}{|a|}$, but it does imply $n>\frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon}-|b|}{|a|}$.

Comment: I'm guessing, following the usual $\epsilon-n$ proofs, that OP is really trying to prove the other way - that if the second expression is true, then the first is. But that's just a guess. Basically, trying to prove that $\frac{1}{an+b}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go from the second to the first expression? I'm trying to prove what Thomas said. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As said by you in the comments, you want $n>\frac{|b|+\frac{1}{\epsilon}}{|a|}\implies \epsilon>\frac{1}{|an+b|}$, not the other way around (which is false, as I said in the comments).

$$n>\frac{|b|+\frac{1}{\epsilon}}{|a|}\implies |an|-|b|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies \epsilon(|an|-|b|)>1$$

$$\implies \epsilon>\frac{1}{|an|-|-b|}\stackrel{(1)}\ge \frac{1}{|an+b|}$$

$(1)$ uses triangle inequality $|x|+|y|\ge |x+y|,\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$.

(proof: $\iff |x|^2+|y|^2+2|xy|\ge (x+y)^2\iff 2|xy|\ge 2xy$).

Answer (score -1):

From $|\dfrac{1}{an+b}|\lt\epsilon$ we get $|an +b|\gt\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$. We know $|an+b|\ge|an|-|b|$ and the rest follows.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but $(|an+b|>\frac{1}{\epsilon})\wedge(|an+b|\ge |an|-|b|)$ does not imply $|an|-|b|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. I suggest deleting this answer to avoid confusing others.